# Why inactive option not working on scatter highcharts

Tags: reactjs, charts, highcharts, scatter, react-highcharts

I have try to show inactive setting in my chart. But it's not showing in my project { it's worked on another live editor }

Chart Library: Highcharts
Chart type: scatter

Chart Version:
"highcharts": "^6.1.1",
"highcharts-more": "^0.1.7","highcharts-react-official": "^3.1.0",

```
``const config = {
chart: {
  zoomType: 'x',
  type: 'scatter',
  height: 400,
  spacingLeft: 0,
  spacingRight: 0,
  spacingTop: 0,
  spacingBottom: 0,
  margin: [30, 50, 80, 180],
  width: null,
  style: {
    fontFamily: 'Fira Sans'
  },
},
title: {
  text: '',
},
subtitle: {
  text: '',
},
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  ordinal: false,
  startOnTick: false,
  endOnTick: false,
  minPadding: 0,
  maxPadding: 0,
  Date: false,
  tickInterval: 3600 * 4000,
  minTickInterval: 3600 * 100,
  minRange: 1000 * 60 * 60,
  dateTimeLabelFormats: {
    minute: '%I:%M',
    hour: '%I %P',
  },
  offset: 0,
},
yAxis: [
  {
    title: {
      text: 'Part A',
      align: "high",
      textAlign: "right",
      rotation: 0,
      offset: 0,
      margin: 0,
      y: -10,
      x: -15,
      style: {
        fontWeight: 500,
        fontSize: '14px',
        lineHeight: 20,
        color: "#333333",
      },
    },
    labels: {
      style: {
        fontWeight: 300,
        fontSize: '14px',
        lineHeight: 16,
        color: "#333333",
        letterSpacing: 0,
      },
      y: 3,
      align:'right',
    },
    categories: ['', 'B1', 'B2', '', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', ''],
  },
  {
    title: {
      text: 'Part B',
      align: "middle",
      textAlign: "right",
      rotation: 0,
      offset: 0,
      margin: 0,
      y: 30,
      x: 25,
      style: {
        fontWeight: 500,
        fontSize: '14px',
        lineHeight: 20,
        color: "#333333",
      },
    },
  },
],
plotOptions: {
  column: {
    stacking: 'normal',
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0,
      borderWidth: 0,
      groupPadding: 0,
      grouping: true,
    }
  },
},
series: [
  {
    "name": "Poor",
    "data": [[1.424304e+12, 1], [1.4243076e+12, 2], [1.4243148e+12, 1], [1.4243301e+12, 1], [1.4243364e+12, 6]],
    color: '#FF8A45',
    marker: {
      symbol: 'square'
    },
  },
  {
    "name": "Fair",
    "data": [[1.424304e+12, 6], [1.4243112e+12, 1], [1.4243292e+12, 2], [1.4243436e+12, 2], [1.4243616e+12, 2]],
    color: '#FFC100',
    marker: {
      symbol: 'square'
    },
  },
  {
    "name": "Moderate",
    "data": [[1.4243616e+12, 4], [1.4243436e+12, 4], [1.4243112e+12, 4], [1.424304e+12, 4], [1.4243292e+12, 6]],
    color: '#B7DCFD',
    
    marker: {
      symbol: 'square'
    },
  },
  {
    "name": "Good",
    "data": [[1.424304e+12, 5], [1.4243112e+12, 5], [1.4243292e+12, 5], [1.4243436e+12, 5], [1.4243616e+12, 6]],
    color: '#00C96A',
    marker: {
      symbol: 'square'
    },
  },
],
credits: {
  enabled: false
},
```

};``

Here is my full config of hoghchart

Comment: I've reproduced your settings in the online demo and it works as expected - scatter hover is enabled, and the other series is active as well : https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hxeapk2t/ . Could you please specify what exactly you would like to achieve?

Comment: It's working in online demo, but not working in my project. So I want to know what is a issue in my code?

Comment: It is hard to tell you what is not working without taking look at your full config. As I said, plotOptions works as expected, so this part of the code is correct. Could you please provide the full chart configuration?

Comment: Hello magdalena, I've edit my full config, Please review my config

Comment: Hi, thanks! Now everything is clear, I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the 6.1.1 version but `inactive` option is available from 7.1.0 https://www.highcharts.com/blog/changelog/#highcharts-v7.1.0 .
I would recommend to always using the latest highcharts version.
So, all you have to do is set `"highcharts": "latest"` in your project.

If for some reason you need to use an older version, use `mouseOver` and `mouseOut` events to change the series color on hover.

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      events: {
        mouseOver: function() {
          let hoveredSeries = this;
          let allSeries = this.chart.series;
          allSeries.forEach(series => {
            if (series === hoveredSeries) {
              return true
            } else if (series.name === 'A') {
              series.update({
                color: 'rgba(0, 155, 0, 0.5)',
              })
            } else if (series.name === 'B') {
              series.update({
                color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)'
              })
            }

          })
        },
        mouseOut: function() {
          let hoveredSeries = this;
          let allSeries = this.chart.series;
          allSeries.forEach(series => {
            if (series === hoveredSeries) {
              return true
            } else if (series.name === 'A') {
              series.update({
                color: 'rgba(0, 155, 0, 1)',
              })
            } else if (series.name === 'B') {
              series.update({
                color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
              })
            }
          })
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

**Example demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zgjsof7L/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.events.mouseOver